# Make a slice of sphere full inside

Tags: modeling

I have a question about modeling a sphere that is fully solid on the inside. I need to take a section of the sphere, as if it were a slice, from the top half (attached photo). I can't figure out how to make the sphere solid on the inside, meaning that there are walls on both sides of the removed section and the remaining section. Thank you very much.[image: sphere section]

Answer (score 4):

You can model this shape by deleting the faces of your selection first.

Then, in edit mode,  <kbd>alt</kbd>   to select the edge loop of the hole.

<kbd>e</kbd>   Extrude all of the points of the edge loop and  <kbd>s</kbd>   resize them so they almost meet.

<kbd>m</kbd>  Merge the vertices at the cursor if it is the object or world origin.

In object mode, select the sphere, and <kbd>rmb</kbd>  to set the shading to auto smooth.

[image]
[image]
[image]

This is a simple way to do it, but not automatic.

Answer (score 4):

Use a boolean modifier. Make a cylinder that is the same number of rings as your sphere. Then delete everything except the "pie slice" you want to extract. Then line it up with the sphere, try to line things up as perfect as you can. Booleans can get messy so if you try to stay exact it will probably work out better.

[image]

It's usually a good idea to give yourself some space "outside" of the mesh you're extracting from, things can get weird if the two meshes overlap too perfectly.

[image]

Then you'll need to duplicate the sphere, add a Boolean modifier with the mode set to "Intersect" to get the inner piece, and the other set to "Difference" to get the sphere with the cutout.

[image]

Or you can just enable the BoolTool addon, which comes built-in. Then just select the cylinder, then the sphere and push "Ctrl+Numpad /" and it does all this automatically.

[image]

Then you just tweak the shading a bit, maybe add a weld modifier to get rid of any doubled vertices and you're good to go.

[image]